# .hgignore being ignored in my Mercurial repo?

Tags: java, android, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using visual tortoiseHg to manage my Mercurial repository, and every time I commit changes I get this whole list of random files that don't normally appear. My `.hgignore` file looks like this:

```
#apks
glob:*.apk
glob:*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
glob:*.dex

# Java class files
glob:*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Ignore gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

#Android Studio
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.iws
.DS_Store
syntax: glob
extras/TODO.md
extras/keystore/keystore.jks
extras/keystore/signing.properties
```

A typical commit looks like this:

[image: Commit summary]

By the way, my `.hgignore` file is in the project root.

Answer (score 0):

For exclude unnessesary folder you need to use *regexp*. 
For example to exclude folder **app** and all folders that include in **app**, use next *regexp*:

```
/app/
```

There is no straightforward way to ignore all but a set of files. Attempting to use an inverted regex match will fail when combined with other patterns. This is an intentional limitation, as alternate formats were all considered far too likely to confuse users to be worth the additional flexibility.
For more information you can read [official documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore).